# clang bug? namespaced template class' friend

Tags: c++, g++, language-lawyer, clang++

The following code which doesn't compile under clang but does under gcc and VS:

```
template<typename T> class bar;

namespace NS
{
    template<typename T>
    class foo
    {
        foo() {}

        template<typename U> friend class bar;
    };
}

template<typename R>
class bar
{
public:
    bar()
    {
        NS::foo<int> f;
    }
};


int main(int, char **)
{
    bar<int> b;        
    return 0;
}
```

It fails with:

```
main.cpp:20:22: error: calling a private constructor of class 'NS::foo<int>'

        NS::foo<int> f;    
                     ^

main.cpp:8:9: note: implicitly declared private here

        foo() {}   
        ^
```

`bar` should have access to `foo`'s private constructor but it looks like it doesn't. If I remove `namespace NS`, it compiles.

Code looks fine to me, but maybe I'm misunderstanding the C++ standard. Which compiler is correct?

Comment: Side note: if you qualify `::bar`, like `template<typename U> friend class ::bar;`, then clang compiles it. So it seems to be something related to friend visibility outside the namespace. Looking at some SO question it seems like clang++ is correct, although I did not (yet) find a dupe.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe that clang is correct. According to [namespace.memdef]/3:

> Every name first declared in a namespace is a member of that namespace. If a `friend` declaration in a
>   non-local class first declares a class, function, class template or function template the friend is a member
>   of the innermost enclosing namespace.

In your case, the name wouldn't appear to be "first declared" by the `friend` declaration. Later in that paragraph, however, emphasis mine:

> If the name in a `friend` declaration is neither qualified nor a *template-id* and
>   the declaration is a function or an *elaborated-type-specifier*, the lookup to determine whether the entity has
>   been previously declared **shall not consider any scopes outside the innermost enclosing namespace**.

That is, this declaration:

```
template<typename U> friend class bar;
```

will not look for `bar` outside of `namespace NS`, so it will not find your earlier declaration. As such, it declares a class template `NS::bar<typename >` to be a `friend` of `foo`. You will have to *qualify* the name `bar` in order for it to be found:

```
template<typename U> friend class ::bar;
```

This seems related to [GCC Bug 37804](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37804).

Answer (score 5):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace):

> Names introduced by friend declarations within a non-local class X
>   become members of the innermost enclosing namespace of X, but they do
>   not become visible to lookup (neither unqualified nor qualified)
>   unless a matching declaration is provided at namespace scope, either
>   before or after the class definition. Such name may be found through
>   ADL which considers both namespaces and classes. Only the innermost
>   enclosing namespace is considered by such friend declaration when
>   deciding whether the name would conflict with a previously declared
>   name.
>
> ```
> void h(int);
> namespace A {
>   class X {
>     friend void f(X); // A::f is a friend
>     class Y {
>         friend void g(); // A::g is a friend
>         friend void h(int); // A::h is a friend, no conflict with ::h
>     };
>   };
>   // A::f, A::g and A::h are not visible at namespace scope
>   // even though they are members of the namespace A
>   X x;
>   void g() {  // definition of A::g
>      f(x); // A::X::f is found through ADL
>   }
>   void f(X) {}       // definition of A::f
>   void h(int) {}     // definition of A::h
>   // A::f, A::g and A::h are now visible at namespace scope
>   // and they are also friends of A::X and A::X::Y
> }
> ```

It's not the standard, but it is in general correct. So clang seems to be right.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the code to

```
template<typename T> class bar;

namespace NS
{
    template<typename T>
    class foo
    {
        foo() {}

        template<typename U> friend class ::bar;
    };
}

template<typename R>
class bar
{
public:
    bar()
    {
        NS::foo<int> f;
    }
};


int main(int, char **)
{
    bar<int> b;

    return 0;
}
```

compiles with clang. The problem seems to be the namespace lookup.
The code

```
template<typename U> friend class bar;
```

actually declared the class NS::bar a friend of NS::foo, so foo should not have been affected. My guess would be that clang is standard conformant and the code should not compile.