# Friend functions and namespaces

Tags: c++

I'm trying to overload the << operator for a class that's part of a user-defined namespace. What's interesting is that if I remove all that namespace stuff, the program compiles and runs without a problem, but the fact that the class resides in a namespace somehow makes the compilation process for the file A.cpp fail with an error saying that I'm trying to access private data in class A (demo.cpp compiles fine). Please, take a look at my three-file program and the compilation error that I get:

demo.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"


int main() {
    usr::A a(4);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

A.h:

```
#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_

#include <iostream>


namespace usr {
    class A {
        private:
            int m_x;
        public:
            A(int x);
            friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const usr::A& a);
    };
}

#endif // A_H_
```

A.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"


usr::A::A(int x) : m_x(x) {}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const usr::A& a) {
    os << a.m_x;
    return os;
}
```

Error:

```
$ g++ -c A.cpp
In file included from A.cpp:1:0:
A.h: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const usr::A&)’:
A.h:10:17: error: ‘int usr::A::m_x’ is private
             int m_x;
                 ^
A.cpp:7:13: error: within this context
     os << a.m_x;
             ^
```

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418270/clang-bug-namespaced-template-class-friend

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Non-qualified friend declarations always refer to members of the smallest enclosing namespace. When a class is declared in namespace `usr`, any non-qualified friend declaration inside that class refers to members of `usr`. I.e. your friend declaration declared `usr::operator <<` as a friend.

The global `::operator <<` remains a non-friend in this case, which is why you get the error when you attempt to access private members of `usr::A` from `::operator <<`.

If you want this to work, you have to either

1. Make your `operator <<` a member of `usr`, or
2. Make sure the friend declaration explicitly refers to global `operator <<` by using a qualified name `::operator <<` (this will also require introducing `::operator <<` *before* trying to refer to it by its qualified name).

I would suggest the first approach. If your class `A` is a member of namespace `usr`, then it is a good idea to declare all functions that handle `A` as members of `usr` as well. This will help you to avoid many problems with argument-dependent lookup (ADL) down the road.

---

But if for some reason you need your `operator <<` to remain a member of global namespace, then here are the hoops you'd have to jump through to make it compile (combined into a single translation unit)

```
// Pre-declare `usr::A` to enable pre-declaration of our `::operator <<`
namespace usr {
    class A;
}

// Pre-declare our `::operator <<`
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const usr::A& a);

namespace usr {
    class A {
        private:
            int m_x;
        public:
            A(int x);
            friend std::ostream& ::operator<<(std::ostream& os, const usr::A& a);
            // Friend declaration uses qualified name - it explicitly 
            // refers to `::operator <<` declared above
    };
}

usr::A::A(int x) : m_x(x) {}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const usr::A& a) {
    os << a.m_x;
    return os;
}

int main() {
    usr::A a(4);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Under GCC you have to separate *return-type* and scope resolution operator (`::` token) via some access modifier (reference on const or pointer).

For example, this **will not** compile under g++7.2.0:

```
std::string f(int a);

namespace NS
{
    class C
    {
        friend std::string ::f(int a);
        // scope operator  ^^ is absolutely needed
    }
}
```

But this **will**:

```
std::string f(int a);

namespace NS
{
    class C
    {
        friend std::string const ::f(int a);
        // see const keyword ^
    }
}
```

And this **will**:

```
std::string f(int a);

namespace NS
{
    class C
    {
        friend std::string& ::f(int a);
        // see ref symbol ^
    }
}
```