# Global scope friend operator declaration when class in namespace and using templated type as return type

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, operators, friend

I am struggling with friend statement for a templated operator and namespaces.
Sorry if I'm a bit long but I want to give a good description of my issue.

First, some context. Forget about the namespace at present.
I have a class `A` and a public operator that needs to access its private member:

```
template<typename U>
struct B { U valb; };

template<typename U>
struct C { U valc; };

template<typename U,typename V>
struct A
{ 
  private:
    U v1; V v2;

  template<typename T1,typename T2>
  friend A<T1,T2> operator * ( const B<T2>&, const C<T1>& );
};

template<typename T1,typename T2>
A<T1,T2>
operator * ( const B<T2>& b, const C<T1>& c )
{
    A<T1,T2> a;
    a.v1 = c.valc * b.valb; // dummy
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    B<float> b;
    C<int> c;
    auto a = b * c;
}
```

This builds fine.

Now for some reason I want to put class `A` in a namespace, (mostly to remove it from the public API, user code will use "sub" types, declared with a `using` declaration).
Now the trouble begins.

I am building on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38801633/193789), that covers that topic and works fine.
It explains that I need to forward declare the class, then the operator, and in the friend declaration, prefix the operator with `::`.

The only difference between the situation described in that linked question and mine is the return type. In my case, it is a templated type. This seems to be the trouble (or is it?)

So I tried that ([online here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ab95f47b8bfe34a)):

```
template<typename U>
struct B { U valb; };

template<typename U>
struct C { U valc; };

// forward declaration of class A
namespace ns {
template<typename U,typename V> struct A;
}

// forward declaration of operator
template<typename T1,typename T2>
ns::A<T1,T2>
operator * ( const B<T2>&, const C<T1>& );

namespace ns {
  template<typename U,typename V>
  struct A                            // class declaration
  {
    template<typename T1,typename T2>
    friend A<T1,T2> ::operator * ( const B<T2>&, const C<T1>& );

    private:
      U v1; V v2;
  };
} // namespace 

// operator definition
template<typename T1,typename T2>
ns::A<T1,T2> operator * ( const B<T2>& b, const C<T1>& c )
{
    ns::A<T1,T2> a;
    a.v1 = c.valc * b.valb; // dummy
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    B<float> b;
    C<int> c;
    auto a = b * c;
}
```

This fails to build with:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'operator*' with no type [-fpermissive]    
   23 |         friend A<T1,T2> ::operator * ( const B<T2>&, const C<T1>& );
```

And if I remove the `::`, then the operator is not recognized as a friend.

What am I doing wrong? How can I manage that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the befriend function template is declared already, I don't think you define this function template outside the class definition: essentially, there is no way to actually name the operator. To make things a bit more interesting, the two parameter types operated on are actually in a different namespace, i.e., the `operator*()` really needs to be defined in a different namespace than `ns`. It seems this does the trick:

```
template<typename U> struct B { U valb; };
template<typename U> struct C { U valc; };

// declaration of ns::A to declare the operator*
namespace ns { template<typename U,typename V> struct A; }

template<typename T1,typename T2>
ns::A<T1,T2> operator * ( const B<T2>&, const C<T1>& );

namespace ns {
    template<typename U,typename V>
    struct A {
        template<typename T1,typename T2>
        friend auto ::operator * ( const B<T2>&, const C<T1>& ) -> A<T1, T2>;

    private:
        U v1; V v2;
    };
}

template<typename T1,typename T2>
ns::A<T1,T2> operator * ( const B<T2>& b, const C<T1>& c ) {
    ns::A<T1,T2> a;
    a.v1 = c.valc * b.valb; // dummy
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    B<float> b;
    C<int> c;
    auto a = b * c;
}
```

For a live demo see this [Compiler Explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/cj9TTbPas).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But... your linked code fails to link??? (`undefined reference to ns::A<int, float> operator*...`. I don't understand why...). Do I miss something?
And any idea why the global qualification works without a templated return type and fails when it is?

Comment: @kebs You are right. I actually didn't quite notice that two arguments operated on are in a different namespace. It turned out to be a somewhat interesting puzzle but I think this [update Compiler Explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/3ocdoq3qG) shows the fix. I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: Ah, ok I see, its the trailing return type that does the trick ! I don't use it very often, so didn't think about trying that. Thanks !